# Sensitive Windows executable files to be blocked in AppLocker

Tags: windows, applocker

I am using `AppLocker` to block what users can access in a virtual machine.

Recently I found out that through an open file dialog the user can type `explorer.exe` and launch `Windows Explorer`.

[image]

A lot of stuff is already blocked, but from that the explorer window, the user can right click `This PC > Properties` and launch the System app from Control Panel. And then he has access to lots of stuff that it should not have.

[image]

For instance, since that window is part of Control Panel, the user can navigate to Control Panel root, launch `Programs and Features` and start uninstalling stuff even though `appwiz.cpl` is blocked in AppLocker. It looks like when stuff is launched from Control Panel directly it cannot be detected by AppLocker, because if I try to lauch `appwiz.cpl` directly it gets blocked.

I guess when this window is launched it is calling an executable file, does anyone knows the name of it so I could include it in AppLocker?

Comment: If you need to lock down Windows so much, consider running in kiosk mode: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, all these tools are displayed by Explorer, so they can't
be blocked by Applocker.

You may instead set a Group Policy to block Settings and Control Panel
as follows:

- Login as administrator
- Run `gpedit.msc`
- Navigate to *User Configuration > Administrative templates > Control Panel*
- Double-click "Prohibit access to Control Panel and PC settings"
- Click Enabled and OK.

For Window Home which does not have the Group Policy editor, the same can
be done via the registry:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER, then follow the path below.

- Run `regedit`
- Position to
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`
- Create a DWORD (32-bit) Value named `NoControlPanel` and
  set it to `1`.

For more information with screenshots, see the article
[How to Block Access to Windows 10 Settings and Control Panel](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/how-to-block-access-to-windows-10-settings-and-control-panel/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was a life saver, and way better than blocking isolated parts of Control Panel